# How does Permission Sets works against Licenses of Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, security, permission-sets, second-generation-packaging, packagelicense

We have built a Second Generation Managed Package and want it to be available as paid version in AppExchange Portal. So If a user buys it from AppExchange, he/she gets the licenses to use the solution.

The answer in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381493/how-managed-package-license-is-counted) question states that an unlicensed user cannot access any components of a Managed Package through UI and Apex doesn't care about licenses or object-level access at all by default and this restriction doesn't include for System Admins.

So My 1st Question is:

Can an unlicensed user access the data of object of managed package through SOQL with SECURITY_ENFORCED Query?

And My 2nd Question is:

What if a user creates a Permission Set and adds the necessary permissions of Managed Package Components and assigns the Permission Set to an Unlicensed User, will the Unlicensed User be able to access the Managed Package Components (Objects, LWC and Aura Components)?

And My 3rd Question is:

Can we clone the Permission Set of a Managed Package and add some permissions of Components of Same Managed Package which are missed in Permission Set provided through Managed Package and can we assign it to a Licensed User?

And How does Normal License (License we get if we buy a package) for a package differs from Namespace Permission Set Licenses in Packages?